# Why do nerve fibres rotate?

Tags: neurophysiology, biophysics, neuroanatomy, neurology

**Background**: Lemniscus (Latin lēmniscus, ribbon) is a strap of second order nerve fibres which twist as they ascend to the brainstem.

---

Why do these these nerve fibres rotate?
 What could be the functional significance of such rotation?

I think that rotation is somewhat less beneficial because firstly it causes increase in length thereby increasing the conduction time , secondly it may decrease structural integrity of such a bundle of axons.

Comment: Why downvote????

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think you are overestimating the amount of twisting that occurs, it isn't going to affect length substantially. If you mean the quarter-turn twist that makes caudal inputs turn lateral and rostral inputs turn medial then indeed this is a very minor twist. Not everything in biology is significant in terms of function, often things are significant for development; a slight twist might help to coalesce the fibers. I'd also say that the structural integrity argument makes no sense, think about how a rope is constructed via twisting smaller fiber strands for strength.

Comment: Okay. Does this make any functional significance just like decussation?

Comment: It is probably relevant for the orientation of the homunculus in, for example, the VPL of the thalamus, but I think it's more an issue of it being important that there is a spatial organization of the fibers, rather than any particular orientation being important.